# How to fix 500 internal server error while using Django and React

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I'm trying to create a simple shopping cart with django and react. When I click on the add-to-cart button I get `500 Internal Server Error` from react. The error it's displaying in django is:
`ValueError: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x00000268F76AEFA0>": "order_product.user" must be a "User" instance.` I have tried every means I know but I'm still not able to fix it. Below is the programme:

```
DJANGO
urls.py 
path('add-to-cart/', add_to_cart_view.as_view(), name='add-to-cart'),
views.py 

class add_to_cart_view(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = request.data.get('id', None)
        if id is None:
            return Response({"message": "Invalid request"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)

        requested_product = order_product.objects.create(
                product=product,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )

        order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
        if order_qs.exists():
            order = order_qs[0]
            if not order.products.filter(product__id=requested_product.id).exists():
                order.products.add(requested_product)
          
                return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            ordered_date = timezone.now()
            order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
            order.products.add(order_product)
            return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

```
REACT
export const AddToCartURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";

const handleAddToCartURL = async (id) => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.post(`${AddToCartURL}/add-to-cart/`, {id});
                setProduct(res.data);
                console.log(res.data)
            }
            catch (err) {

            }
        };


    return(
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} m={4}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={9}>
                    <Item>
                       <img src={product.image} alt="" />
                       <div>
                           <p>{product.description}</p>
                           <p>{product.label}</p>
                           <p>{product.price}</p>

                       </div>
                       <button color='primary' onClick={() => handleAddToCartURL(product.id)}>
                            <AddShoppingCartIcon />
                        </button>  
                    </Item>                  
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs>
                    <Item>Similar Products</Item>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
    
      </Box>
    )
}
export default ProductDetails
```

I really dont't understand why it is returning anonymous user from django. Please how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You have this error because the user you try to assign is **not authenticated***.
Add a permission to your view like this :

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class add_to_cart_view(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    
    # Rest of the code here
```

**NB :** You will need to authenticate the user before make a post request.

**UPDATE :** If you want to test with non authenticated user.
You can create a generic user for that :

```
# Create a user with a name unauthenticated_user in the admin

# In the view :
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # Do something for authenticated users.
    # Your code previous code here
else:
    # retrieve the unauthenticated_user you create 
    # use your custom user here
```

Comment: Thank you @Rvector. Please, I would like to know: Is it not possible for me to test the `add to cart url` functionality without authentication. I'm asking because I haven't set up authentication in the react app.

Comment: Of course it is possible. You can create a generic user. And set it if user is not authenticated

Comment: thanks. I have no idea as to how to implement that