# Django + React App in Azure gives a server error - 500 everytime

Tags: django, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a Django app to Azure through Github actions to Azure app service. But it gives a Server error 500 everytime. I have configured the static files and react template properly. In the Diagnose tab there's no error is displaying. How can I troubleshoot and find the error or Is there any other things to configure in Azure? I hosted a same copy in Heroku and it works there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the below steps:

1. `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` – With this setting set to true - Kudu will execute build steps on your site during deployment.
2. `DEBUG = 0` - please check (if this can make any change) after adding this config to your configuration.
3. You need to enable the `Detailed error pages` in your portal. This may give a detailed log to know why it happened.
4. Try Adding Application Insights to your App to check the detailed logs

Best practices to deploy your [Application](https://stories.mlh.io/deploying-a-basic-django-app-using-azure-app-services-71ec3b21db08)

Refer  here [Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/449267/500-server-error-on-django-on-app-service-when-deb.html) & [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875907/how-to-fix-500-internal-server-error-while-using-django-and-react)